# TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components in python

Tags: kivy, python-3.7, pyjnius, kivymd

```
 Using cached jnius-1.1.0.tar.gz (28 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-instal
l-g13whan3\\jnius\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g13whan3\\jnius\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.
read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-94rlagf8'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g13whan3\jnius\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    WARNING: Not able to assign machine() = AMD64 to a cpu value!
             Using cpu = 'i386' instead!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g13whan3\jnius\setup.py", line 153, in <module>
        join(jre_home, 'bin', 'server')
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in join
        genericpath._check_arg_types('join', path, *paths)
      File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\genericpath.py", line 151, in _check_arg_types
        raise TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components") from None
    TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Getting this error while downloading jnius package First it showed Cython package is missing after installing Cython I tried to install jnius then it showed above error then I tried installing pyjnius and it showed

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied